# Switch (internal) tab using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I've been trying to access elements of a website using Selenium but keep getting this message :

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

The problem I'm having seems to be that the website uses the same classes' name between two tabs, and just changes the visibility of one to display the other. For instance, when the first tab is displayed the first div's visibility is visible and the second is hidden. If the second tab is displayed, then the second div is visible, and the first hidden.

[image: strong text]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For the first tab, I have no problem accessing the desired elements. However, if the second tab is displayed, I get the above error message.

Is there a way to switch between to div like one would do between two iframe ?

This is what my code looks like for the moment :

```
driver.get(url) #get url
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ctl00_cphMaster_ConsultationCitoyenCriteresRecherche_CritereRechercheTabContainer_RechercheSimpleTabPanel_RechercheSimpleControl_MotsClesTextBox']").send_keys(string) #enter searched term
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ctl00_cphMaster_ConsultationCitoyenCriteresRecherche_CritereRechercheTabContainer_RechercheSimpleTabPanel_RechercheSimpleControl_PorteeRadioButtonList_1']").click() 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='Bouton BoutonRechercher']").click() #click the search button
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='Header']")))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__tab_ctl00_cphMaster_ConsultationCitoyenResultatsRecherche_ResultatsRechercheTabContainer_RechercheLETabPanel"]').click() #switch tab
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='Header']")))

while True:
    listings = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("InscriptionSummaryValue")
    c = 1
    for i in listings:
        page = int(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='CurrentPage']").text) #can't find the element because it seems to be located in the first div
```

Comment: From what I understand when the visibility is set to hidden, the data of the hidden table is still there in the html, so you should be able to get it. Try to run this command `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ajax__tab_panel' and contains(@style,'visibility: hidden')].get_attribute('outerHTML')"` what does it return?

Comment: You probably just need a webdriverwait or a standard sleep.  Not sure why you are iterating or getting that element array there.  Doesn't seem like you use "i" at all.  Not sure why you use webdriverwaits for presence of a div with 'Header' style either.  That won't tell you that it's interactable or even visible.  You could have a progress indicator showing, or content that is still loading.

Comment: you may need a more targeted locator, or at least grab them all and check for visibility... there is also an expected condition for visibilityOf.... that you could use with a webdriverwait.  Timing may be an issue if your locator is picking up both visible and invisible elements.  (a standard sleep might be best since you need to consider when one turns visible and the other invisible...)